# Should we send [open-source] packing?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I've just discovered that we have an [open-source](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source) tag.  This tag appears to be useless because, as per SE's [CC BY-SA license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), all material posted is subject to public use within the guidelines.  Alongside that, these questions have nothing else in common, and it seems to be an older tag.

Burninate?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's for asking questions about open source software.

Burn it:

- Hardly used
- Add nothing interesting to the question

Burn if for similar reasons that the [homework](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-discourage-the-use-of-and-burninate-the-homework-tag) tag was burned on SO.

See also [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) except that there is IMO some reason/excuse for keeping [beginner](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) on this site.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for the reasons cited in the question.